# Call ToString() on a dynamically build expression

Tags: c#, reflection, expression, expression-trees

I'm trying to build an dynamic expression from a string of property-names (given by the user) on an IQueryable named `source`.
This is what I have so far:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "x");
var member = propertyChain.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
var selector = Expression.Lambda(member, parameter);
```

which will give me something like `x => x.MainProperty.SubProperty` when the input would be `MainProperty.SubProperty`.

I now need to add `ToString()` to the expression `selector` so it will produce the expression `x => x.MainProperty.SubProperty.ToString()` which then can be passed into other methods.

How can this be done?

## Edit 1

I'm trying to build a dynamic `GroupBy` where the type of the key doesn't matter. But the property to group by can be of type `Guid`, `int` or something else. That's why I need to call `ToString()`.

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, T>>(IQueryable<T> source, string propertyChain)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "x");
    var member = propertyChain.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.PropertyOrField);
    var selector = Expression.Lambda(member, parameter);

    // currently here I have x => x.MainProperty.SubProperty
    // here I would Invoke the GroupBy of IQueryable with T and string via reflection
}
```

Comment: Can you give a working example?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I've added an example of what I'm going to achieve at least with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following [`Expression.Call`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336138(v=vs.110).aspx) overload for instance:

```
var toString = Expression.Call(member, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(toString, parameter);
return source.GroupBy(selector);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Now I can group whatever I like to ;). Thanks

Comment: How can I convert a list of strings (`{"PropertyOne", "PropertyTwo"}`) to have the `selector` be `s => s.PropertyOne + "|" + s.PropertyTwo` where the list can contain a unknown number of strings?

Comment: You can  use `Expression.Call` to one of the `string.Concat` overloads (for instance [`String.Concat Method (String, String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e285t1h(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Let say you use the above to create 2 expressions - `toString1` and `toString2`. Then the body of the selector would be `Expression.Call(typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) }), toString1, Expression.Constant("|"), toString2)`

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks again! Seems you know quite much about this Expression-stuff ;-). Any tutorials/books you would/can recommend?

Comment: can we make ToString() like ToString("f") with this? @IvanStoev

Comment: @MuhammedYILMAZ You can create such *expression*  if the type supports such method (not all do) by adding argument to the call, e.g. `Expression.Call(member, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant("f"))`. But it would be useless if the used with db query provider (like EF / EF Core), because such methods are not translatable to SQL.